# JSON String add Link

Tags: php, html, json

I´ve got the a php that returns a JSON string:

```
$recipes = json_encode($arr);
```

That is my php-code how I output the recipe-title:

```
<?php
 include('php/getAllRecipes.php');
 $jsonstring = $recipes;
 $recip = json_decode($recipes, true);
 $i = 1;
 var data = include('php/getAllRecipes.php')Data.Recipes;
foreach ($recip['Data']['Recipes'] as $key => $recipe) {
        echo "$i.) &nbsp ";
        echo  $recipe['TITLE'];
        $i = $i + 1;
        echo "<br>";
 } 
 ?>
```

Now, I need to add a href to each title. The href should contain a link to `recipe_search.php` and I have to give it the id of each recipe. 
How can I add this href?

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($recipes)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 include('php/getAllRecipes.php');
 $jsonstring = $recipes;
 $recip = json_decode($recipes, true);
?>
<ol>
<?php
foreach ($recip['Data']['Recipes'] as $key => $recipe) {
        echo '<li>
                  <a href="/recipe_search.php?id=' . $recipe['ID'] . '">
                      ' . $recipe['TITLE'] . '
                  </a>
              </li>';
 } 
 ?>
</ol>
```

1. Use an ordered list (`<ol>`) instead of trying to create one yourself using a counter.
2. `var data = include('php/getAllRecipes.php')Data.Recipes;` is not valid PHP.
3. I assume that the id of the recipe is in `$recipe['ID']`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are...

```
foreach ($recip['Data']['Recipes'] as $key => $recipe)
{
    // I guess $key is ID of your recipe...
    echo  sprintf('%d.) <a href="%s">%s</a><br />', $i++, 'recipe_search.php?id=' . $key, $recipe['TITLE']);
}
```

Thats worked for me, just to test the above:

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach (array_fill(0, 40, 'recipe') as $key => $recipe)
    {
        // I guess $key is ID of your recipe...
        echo  sprintf('%d.) <a href="%s">%s</a><br />', $i++, 'recipe_search.php?id=' . $key, $recipe);
    }
?>
```